# Añadir botones con imágenes de forma dinámica, no se muestran las imágenes

Tags: python, imagen, tkinter, botón, bucles

Tengo el siguiente código, que me añade 30 botones como máximo a un panel de Tkinter. Los botones tienen la misma imagen y funcionan todos.

```
    romper = False
    filas = 5
    columnas = 6
    self.voll = PhotoImage(file="/home/manu/Escritorio/mc/ICONOS/volldamm.png")
    #no incluyo los cálculos para los place de los botones, 
    #que permiten colocar los botones de forma proporcional, 
    #funcionando el código para distintos números de filas y columnas.
    for pu in range (0,filas):
        for pi in range (0,columnas):
            if len(listaProductos)>pi+pu*filas:
                vollboton = Button(master, text ="", command = voll)
                vollboton.config(image=self.voll)
                vollboton.place(x=pi*relacion+self.padX,y=pu*relacion+self.padY)
            else:
                romper = True
                break
        if romper:
            break
```

Sin embargo, si trato de cargar las imágenes desde la lista de productos del programa (están en una base de datos con un campo imagen), lo que me ocurre es que solo aparece la imagen y la funcionalidad del último de los botones antes del break.

```
    romper = False
    filas = 5
    columnas = 6
    for pu in range (0,filas):
        for pi in range (0,columnas):
            if len(listaProductos)>pi+pu*filas:
                image = datos.dameProducto(listaProductos[pi +pu*filas])[0][5]
                # Retorna volldamm.png, heineken.png,....
                prod = PhotoImage(file="/home/manu/Escritorio/mc/ICONOS/"+image+"")
                vollboton = Button(master, text ="", command = voll)
                vollboton.config(image=prod)
                vollboton.place(x=pi*relacion+self.padX,y=pu*relacion+self.padY)
            else:
                romper = True
                break
        if romper:
            break
```

¿Cómo podría implementar esto correctamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es un problema muy común, el recolector de basura haciendo de las "suyas".

Cuando haces:

```
prod = PhotoImage(file="...")
```

estás creando una instancia de la clase `tk.PhotoImage`. Este objeto mantiene una referencia gracias al identificador `pro`, el problema es que en la siguiente iteración se crea un nuevo objeto y `pro` deja de hacer referencia al anterior para hacerla al nuevo objeto. ¿Cuál es el problema? Pues que cuando se hace:

```
vollboton.config(image=prod)
```

en ningún momento se crea una nueva referencia al objeto, esto implica que cuando `pro` pasa a hacer referencia a la siguiente imagen, la anterior se queda sin referencias y el GC lo detecta y manda el objeto a mejor vida quedando el botón sin imagen.

La solución es tan simple como mantener una referencia viva en tu programa de cada imagen mientras estas sean necesarias, puedes usar una lista para ello, algo así:

```
images = []  # Lista encargada de mantener una referencia a cada imágen

filas = 5
columnas = 6

romper = False
for pu in range (filas):
    for pi in range (columnas):
        if len(listaProductos)>pi+pu*filas:
            image = datos.dameProducto(listaProductos[pi +pu*filas])[0][5]
            # Retorna volldamm.png, heineken.png,....
            prod = PhotoImage(file="/home/manu/Escritorio/mc/ICONOS/{}".format(image))
            images.append(prod)  # Añadimos la instancia a la lista
            vollboton = Button(master, text ="", command = voll)
            vollboton.config(image=prod)
            vollboton.place(x=pi*relacion+self.padX, y=pu*relacion+self.padY)
        else:
            romper = True
            break
    if romper:
        break
```

> **IMPORTANTE:** la lista debe tener el mismo tiempo de vida que los botones. Por ejemplo, si creas los botones dentro de una función la lista debe ser una variable global para evitar que sea destruida cuando la función retorne, si los creas en un método la lista debe ser un atributo de clase, etc

---

Lo anterior es una forma general de hacerlo y que sirve para cualquier situación en la que usemos una serie de imágenes en la app. Si tenemos una aplicación que va a reutilizar una serie de imágenes a menudo puede interesar crear una especie de "cache" que evite volver a cargar una imagen cargada con anterioridad, para ello podemos usar la misma aproximación pero cambiando la lista por un diccionario con las rutas como clave.

No obstante otra opción aún mas simple para casos concretos como este  es forzar que el propio objeto mantenga la referencia a su imagen:

```
prod = PhotoImage(file="/home/manu/Escritorio/mc/ICONOS/{}".format(image))
vollboton = Button(master, text ="", command=voll)
vollboton.image = prod   # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
vollboton.config(image=prod)
```

---

Personalmente en estos casos prefiero crear una clase propia que herede del widget de turno para facilitar el manejo de la imagen y mantener el encapsulamiento en el objeto:

```
import tkinter as tk
import logging
import os

module_logger = logging.getLogger('main')

class ImageButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, image_path=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('main.ImageButton')
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s] <%(name)s>: %(message)s')
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(ch)

        self._image_path = None
        self._image = None
        self.image_path = image_path

    @property
    def image_path(self):
        return self._image_path

    @image_path.setter
    def image_path(self, path):
        path = os.path.abspath(path)
        try:
            self._image = tk.PhotoImage(file=path)
            self.config(image=self._image)
            self._image_path = path
        except tk.TclError:
            self.logger.warn("No se pudo cargar la imagen desde '{}'".format(path))


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.button = ImageButton(self,
                                  image_path="img1.png",
                                  text="",
                                  command=self.change_image
                                 )
        self.button.pack()

    def change_image(self):
        self.button.image_path = "img2.png"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

Comment: Gracias por la explicación. Quizá es porque no he puesto todo el código de la clase, pero no me funciona tu código. Creo que olvidé poner self.prod = Photoimage. No sé por qué muy bien, pero en el código de mi respuesta por ejemplo, no funciona si las variable image no es global.

Comment: funciona perfectamente sin necesidad de generar el array images y añadiendo las cyuatro líneas en el bucle if, usando el código que muestras, y es más limpia que mi solución. ty

Comment: lo único que en mi caso estoy escribiendo sobre master y no self (tk.Button(master,text="")

Comment: No entiendo cómo es que `vollboton.config(image=prod)` no crea una referencia a `prod`. Aún sin saber qué hace esa función, cabe supoenr que almacene lo que recibe como parámetro en algún atributo del objeto, digamos por ejemplo que el código contiene algo del estilo `self.image=image`. Eso ya contaría como una referencia para evitar que el recolector de basura se lo lleve, ¿no? De no ser así no entiendo qué sentido tendría pasarle esa imagen como parámetro.

Comment: @FJSevilla Oh, parece que sí que [es como dices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html?highlight=button#images) y no se guardan referencias a las imágenes. Pero entonces no entiendo qué hace el método `Button.config()`. Supongo que tendré que mirar el código fuente...

Comment: @abulafia no se exactamente por qué los desarrolladores no implementaron en el propia clase Python esto, ya que es trivial como comentas y confunde mucho. Tkinter tiene sus peculiaridades, hay que tener presente que es en realidad una capa sobre Tcl/Tk que tiene su propio intérprete y Tkinter básicamente actúa como intermediario. Parece que Tk mantiene una referencia al objeto interno pero tkinter no, cuando el GC destruye la imagen, tkinter le "comunica" a Tk que libere la imagen, como esta siendo usada por un widget no lo hace completamente, simplemente la hace trasparente....

Comment: Me adscribo no entiendo como aprendiz que el bucle del post funciona solo con vollboton.image = prod cuando se le pasa prod. supongo que es por el tipo de almacenamiento particular de python al crear el atributo el colector ya no se lo lleva. curioso que funciona igualmente para vollboton.config(image=volboton.image). Quizá tenga que ver con que python es también un lenguaje scripting y aspira a sustituir a matlab en toma de datos de satélites etc por lo que la optimización es importante para esos programadores @FJSevilla, desde mi ignorancia de cómo funciona el tipado de veras.

Comment: @code_learner el GC en cpython lo que hace es detectar objetos en memoria cuyo **contador de referencias está a cero**. Es decir, cuando encuentra un objeto que no tiene nada que haga referencia a él el GC lo destruye automáticamente. Cuando se hace `vollboton.config(image=...)` se llama a una función que se comunica con el intérprete tcl/TK que hay por debajo, pero no se crea ninguna referencia a la imagen en el objeto Python.

Comment: Con `vollboton.image = prod` lo que hacemos es crear un nuevo atributo en el objeto `vollboton` que hace referencia a la imagen (tanto `prod` como `vollboton.image` apuntan ahora al mismo objeto en memoria, por eso  `vollboton.config(image=volboton.image)` y  `vollboton.config(image=prod)` son lo mismo), por lo que mientras el botón exista el contador de referencias va a ser al menos uno para la imagen y el GC le perdonará la vida. Ten en cuenta que cuando hacemos `v2 = v1` lo único que pasa es que a `v2` se le asigna la misma referencia (dirección de memoria) del objeto al que apunta `v1`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné introduciendo arrays y separando la parte de calcular la cuadrícula de la de colocar los botones, no sé si de forma algo ineficiente.

```
    posiciones = []
    nomImagenes = []
    self.imagenes = []
    for pu in range (0,filas):
        for pi in range (0,columnas):
            if len(listaProductos)>pi+pu*filas:
                image = datos.dameProducto(listaProductos[pi +pu*filas])[0][5]
                nomImagenes.append(image)
                posicion = [pi*relacion+self.padX,pu*relacion+self.padY]
                posiciones.append(posicion)
            else:
                romper = True
                break
        if romper:
            break
    for ik in range (len(posiciones)):
        self.image = PhotoImage(file="/home/manu/Escritorio/mc/ICONOS/"+nomImagenes[ik]+"")
        self.imagenes.append(self.image)
    for ih in range (len(posiciones)):
        boton = Button(master, text ="", command = voll)
        boton.config(image=self.imagenes[ih])
        boton.place(x=posiciones[ih][0],y=posiciones[ih][1])
```

Comment: Vease la solución marcada como mejor. Añadiendo las cuatro líneas en el if el código es más limpio y eficiente.