# No muestra las imagenes

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.x

Estoy practicando con Python 2 y Tkinter, el problema es que cuando trato de agregar una imagen esta no  aparece.

El código es este:

```
image= tk.PhotoImage("1473185883EMBW_07.gif")
image=image.subsample(1,1)
label=tk.Label(image=image)
label.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1.0,relheight=1.0)
label.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
```

pero cuando lo ejecuto no me sale ningún error pero la imagen no aparece, aparece un pequeñísimo punto blanco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Aunque no está muy bien documentada, el primer argumento del inicializador de la clase `tkinter.PhotoImage` (aparte de `self`) es `name`, que por defecto es `None` y que es común al resto de widgets. Básicamente permite definir un nombre que identifica la instancia y que es necesario para Tk (por lo que Tkinter siempre define uno automáticamente si no se provee) aunque con casi nula utilidad en Tkinter en sí. Puedes confirmar esto haciendo `print(image.name)` justo debajo de la instancia de `PhotoImage` (lo que te imprimirá tu ruta).

Para evitar que la ruta sea tomada como valor del argumento `name` usa  la *keyword* `file`:

```
image= tk.PhotoImage(file="1473185883EMBW_07.gif")
```

`PhotoImage` también acepta imágenes GIF codificadas en base64 (strings), en este caso se usa el argumento `data`:

```
image = tk.PhotoImage(data=string_base64)
```

Debes **mantener en todo momento una referencia a la imagen**, esto es relevante si este código está en una función o método e `image` es una variable local, mírate esta pregunta y mi respuesta relacionada con esto:

[Añadir botones con imágenes de forma dinámica en Python Tkinter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/162097/15089)

Siempre deberías pasar a cada widget su padre si lo tiene, es fundamental a la hora de aplicar `pack`/`grid`/`place` porque puedes terminar creando el widgets en el contenedor equivocado por ejemplo:

```
import Tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
image= tk.PhotoImage(file="1473185883EMBW_07.gif")
label=tk.Label(root, image=image)
label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Por último dos observaciones (no se si son fruto de que estés probando cosas): no tiene mucho sentido que uses dos *geometry managers* sobre el mismo widget, al final solo vas a aplicar el último (`pack` en tu caso). Por otro lado, el uso del método `subsample` con `(1, 1)` como argumentos se limita a copiar la imagen, dado que no hay factor de escalado alguno.