# Imagen se imprime en el canvas sólo si salta error

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estoy intentando averiguar que está pasando en mi código que la imagen que intento imprimir en mi canvas sólo aparece si tengo un error, y sin embargo si no lo tengo no la imprime.

```
def printScreen(self):
    global capname, number, capture, array

    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:/Motic/Motic Images Plus 2.0/Capture Folder",
                    title = "Select capture",filetypes = (("bmp files","*.bmp"),("all files","*.*")))
    capture = Image.open(filename)

    splitter = filename.split("/")
    capname = splitter[-1].split(".")

    splitter = filename.split("_")
    number = splitter[-1].split(".")
    number = int(number[0]) - 1

    path = 'C:/Motic/Motic Images Plus 2.0/Capture Folder'
    array = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.bmp'))

    im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(capture)

    self.imgArea = self.canvas.create_image(180, 20, anchor = NW, image = im)
    self.canvas.pack(fill=None, expand=False)

    print("--before--")
    im.pack()            #aquí es donde me da el error
    print("--after--")
```

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1541, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)
>     File "parabox.py", line 55, in printScreen
>       im.pack()
>   AttributeError: PhotoImage instance has no attribute 'pack'

Por otro lado, si elimino la fila en la que me da el error, ya no salta, e imprime "--before--" y "--after--", pero no me imprime la imagen.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Efectivamente `PhotoImage` no tiene el método `pack`, no es un widget. Esto debes hacerlo con el canvas solo. El por qué no aparece la imagen es el mismo problema que: [Añadir botones con imágenes de forma dinámica, no se muestran las imágenes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/162097/15089), debes mantener una referencia a `im` después del retorno del método (por ejemplo `self.canvas.im = im`) o el recolector de basura la mandará a paseo . Ahora mismo `im` es una variable local y dejará de existir en cuanto `printScreen` retorne y con ella la imagen del canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias FJSevilla por la aclaración, me ha servido mucho. He probado a mantener la referencia y ya ha funcionado.

También parece que funciona si en vez de introducir la imagen mediante `canvas.create_image` la introduzco mediante etiquetas, así:

```
self.im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(capture)
tk.Label(self,image = self.im).place(x=180, y=20, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

Comment: Efectivamente, eso también funciona sin problemas, aunque lo importante no es que se use un `Label` o `Canvas`, la clave está en `self.im = ImageTk....`, con esto creas (si no existía ya) un **atributo de instancia** que mantendrá su referencia al objeto mientras la instancia no sea destruida, por lo tanto la referencia seguirá viva después del retorno del método.

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que `ImageTk.PhotoImage` no es un widget de Tkinter, por lo que no tiene método `pack`. La imagen se puede mostrar mediante un algún widget que lo soporte como `Canvas`, `Label` o `Button` pasandola al argumento `image`. Es este widget el que debemos posicionar mediante `place`, `pack` o `grid`, no la imagen.

El problema causante de que no se muestre la imagen se debe a que `im` es una variable local del método `printScreen`, en cuanto este retorne el recolector de basura destruye el objeto y la imagen desaparece. La solución es mantener una referencia a la imagen que viva como mínimo lo que dure el canvas. Hay muchas formas de hacerlo dependiendo de la situación; crear un atributo de instancia del widget que la usa (`self.canvas.im = im`), de la instancia de la clase `self.im = im`, asociarla a una variable global, etc

La siguiente pregunta muestra el mismo problema y en su respuesta se explica mejor este problema:

[Añadir botones con imágenes de forma dinámica, no se muestran las imágenes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/162097/15089)

Bien, dicho esto la verdadera intención de la respuesta es explicar por qué ocurre lo que menciona el título de dicha pregunta: ¿Por qué la imagen se imprime en el canvas solo si salta error?

Vamos a partir de un ejemplo muy simple:

```
import Tkinter as tk
# import tkinter as tk # Python 3
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        capture = Image.open("python.png")
        im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(capture)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.imgArea = self.canvas.create_image(200, 140, anchor= "center", image = im)
        self.canvas.pack(fill=None, expand=False)
        im.pack()            #aquí es donde me da el error



app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Si ejecutamos el código en la terminal llamando al intérprete `$ python mi_módulo.py` nos lanza la excepción y ni siquiera se inicia la interfaz ya que el `__init__` no se completa y el **intérprete termina a causa de la excepción**.

Ahora bien, la cosa cambia si **ejecutas el código desde un intérprete interactivo** (IDLE, terminal IPython de Spyder, etc). Una excepción no manejada causa la terminación del intérprete, pero esto no es así con el interprete interactivo (no tendría sentido), en su lugar se limita solo a imprimir dicha excepción.

Además de no terminar su ejecución, el intérprete interactivo **almacena la excepción actual** (la última excepción producida) por si el usuario quiere hacer una depuración post-mortem. Podemos acceder a ella vía `sys.last_type`/`sys.last_traceback`/`sys.last_value`, `sys.exc_info`, ...

Sin entrar en el fondo de como se almacena internamente una excepción en Python hay que tener presente que un objeto `Exception` **mantiene una referencia a los objetos implicados en dicha excepción**. En nuestro caso por ejemplo el objeto al que apunta `im`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se observa, al provocar otra excepción la anterior es substituida perdiéndose con ella la referencia e `im` y el GC entra en acción inmediatamente desapareciendo la imagen.

Podemos obtener el mismo comportamiento fuera del intérprete interactivo si manejamos la excepción y la asignamos a una variable local:

```
import Tkinter as tk
#import tkinter as tk  # Python 3
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        capture = Image.open("python.png")
        im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(capture)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.imgArea = self.canvas.create_image(200, 140, anchor= "center", image = im)
        self.canvas.pack(fill=None, expand=False)

        try:
            im.pack()            #aquí es donde me da el error
        except Exception as e:
            result = e



app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

En el código anterior estamos **asociando una variable local (`result`) a una excepción en el mismo frame que la causa** y esto crea una **referencia cíclica** ya que el frame mantiene una referencia a su variable local como es normal y a su vez la variable local mantiene una referencia al frame. Nuestro buen GC basado en contador de referencias no va a destruir ningún objeto aunque el `__init__` retorne a causa de la referencia cíclica (los contadores de referencias nunca llegan a cero), lo cual mantiene `im` en memoria  y nos muestra la imagen.

Python tiene una "segunda versión del GC" (*cyclic garbage collector*) encargado de detectar y limpiar las referencias cíclicas si está activado, pero a diferencia del GC por contador de referencias no funciona continuamente (es mucho más complejo e ineficiente) y solo podemos asumir que es posible que en algún momento indeterminado en el futuro la detecte y la elimine.

Este problema se solventa por ejemplo usando adecuadamente la cláusula `finally` para decrementar las referencias a las variables implicadas vía `del`, o usando `traceback.clear_frames()` (Python 3):

```
    try:
        im.pack()            #aquí es donde me da el error
    except Exception as e:
        result = e
    finally:
        del result
```