# error Abrir Imagen con PIL python

Tags: python

No logro abrir un imagen siendo que le doy el path correcto. agredeceria saber cual es el problema.el directorio de la imagen esta anterior al directorio del programa.

```
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path

cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)


data_folder = Path(cwd)
nombre_imagen="icononoche.png"
file_to_open = data_folder / nombre_imagen
imagen= Image.open(file_to_open)`
```

el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Camila, bienvenida a [es.so] ¿Te has asegurado de que la ruta mostrada en el  error es correcta? ¿La imagen es seguro png (independientemente de la extensión) y el archivo no está corrupto? **¿Has instalado  PIL o PIllow?**

Comment: Hola,gracias por responder,si es la ruta mostrada, es png, y tengo instalado PIL el mas actualizado.

Comment: ahora sobre el archivo corrupto... es extraño dice 'parece que el formato de este archivo no es compatible', pero, yo consumo dos imagenes de la web, iconodia.png e icononoche.png, y la segunda no tiene problemas al abrirse

Comment: Si ejecutas en un script lo siguiente que te muestra, es solo por descartar algunas cosas: `import PIL;print(PIL.PILLOW_VERSION)`. En cuanto a la imagen, ¿sería posible que la subieras para ver si se puede reproducir el problema?

Comment: ahora probe icononoche que no tiene problemas al consumirse, el codigo de Image.open, no me da error, pero al hacer al Label :lblicd=Label(f,image=imagen) me da error : (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=75x45 at 0x1FAF855C470>" doesn't exist

Comment: No puedes pasar una imagen directamente, debe hacer `from PIL import Image, ImageTk; imagen_label = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen);lblicd=Label(f,image=imagen_label)`

Comment: gracias.al parecer, ahora no da problemas, aunque la imagen carga, no aparece, solo aparece un espacio que es el que se supone esta ocupando, en la pregunta te dejo una imagen, por ultimo, sabes porque esto pasa?

Comment: Por cierto, la imagen que has subido a mi al menos no me da problemas con la versión más reciente (`Pillow 6.1.0`). Si de verdad instalaste PIL (`pip install pil`) desintala e instala su fork pillow (`pip install pillow`), PIL es un proyecto no mantenido. LA sintaxis y los imports no cambian. Por eso te pedía arriba  lo de `import PIL;print(PIL.PILLOW_VERSION)`...

Comment: el icono que subi es el que no daba problemas, el iconodia, si, por eso no pude subirlo, porque tarda en descargar de la pagina web

Comment: Vale,pues seguramente el archivo está dañado... En cuanto al espacio en blanco, debes dejar una referencia a la imagen mientra el label exista: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/162097/15089. Esto es espcialemnte relevante si añades la imagen en fuera del espacio de nombres global, por ejemplo en una función o método o si reasigna otra cosa a la variable. Si no te aclaras agrega el código completo que usas a tu pregunta.

Comment: claro, habia intentando usando PhotoImage, pero me dio el mismo problema de estar en blanco, subire el codigo completo

Comment: El tema no es usar tkinter.Photoimage o PIL sino mantener viva una  referencia de la imagen, por ejemplo haciendo `lblicd.image = imagen_label`, aunque para saber seguro que es esto hay que ver dónde instancias `imagen_label`

Comment: bueno la pagina no me dejo subir el codigo xd, ya que era mucho en relacion a la publicacion, pero intentare lo que comentas

Comment: muchas gracias funciono perfectamente :)