# ¿Cómo agregar dinamicamente una imagen a un Button Tkinter python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente problema creo varios botones dinamicamente pero al agregar la imagen, esta no es dinámica

```
def create_button(val, pos):
imga = PhotoImage(file="images/mesa{}.png".format(val + 1))
print(imga)
Button(master, image=imga, command=lambda arg1=i: prueba_evento(arg1)).place(x=pos, y=0)
```

Comment: No especificas que quieres decir con "no es dinámica", pero el problema de tu código es que debes mantener una referencia a imga mientras el botón exista. Si este es tu único problema, la pregunta es un duplicado de [Añadir botones con imágenes de forma dinámica, no se muestran las imágenes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/162097/15089). En tu caso deberías hacer algo como  `btn = Button(master, ...); btn.imga = imga;  btn.place(...)`. Si con esto sigues con problemas explica más detalladamente que es lo que ocurre.

Comment: Muchas gracias!, con el enlace que me enviaste y creando la lista ya me cargan las imagenes correctamente