# Problemas con módulos, objetos y atributos en python

Tags: python, poo, tkinter, atributos

Tengo un programa en el que he metido cada clase en un módulo diferente. El caso es que una de esas clases/módulos, llamada `ventana`, recibe en el constructor como parámetro un `tkinter.Toplevel()`, al que después quiero acceder desde un método diferente al constructor dentro de esa misma clase/módulo `ventana`

aquí el código implicado en la clase/módulo en la que creamos el `tkinter.Toplevel()`:

```
from imagen import ventana_imagenes
v = tkinter.Toplevel()
ventana(v)
```

aquí el constructor de la clase `ventana` recibiendo como parámetro el objeto:

```
class ventana:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.mi_BBDD = BBDD()
        self.crear_pregunta(master)
```

Y aquí el método de la clase `ventana` donde quiero volver a usar el objeto `tkinter.Toplevel()` creado al inicio:

```
def siguiente(self, contenedor):
        contenedor.destroy() # contenedor hace referencia a otro Toplevel diferente
        self.crear_pregunta() # el problema es que no sé como pasarle el contenedor correcto como argumento a este método
        self.b_siguiente.grid()
```

Espero haberme explicado con suficiente claridad, ya que yo mismo estoy hecho un lío.

---

### **Edición**

He probado a añadir el `self.master` como atributo en el `__init__` pero sigo obtengo el siguiente error:

> AttributeError: 'ventana' object has no attribute 'master'

Este es mi código completo, con el atributo añadido:

```
import tkinter as tk
from Conexion import BBDD
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import io

class ventana_imagenes:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.mi_BBDD = BBDD()
        self.crear_pregunta(master)
        self.master = master




    def crear_pregunta(self, master):       
        self.num = random.sample(range(1,5),4) 
        self.mezcla = random.sample(range(0,4),4) 
        self.relacion = {self.mezcla[0]:self.num[0], self.mezcla[1]:self.num[1], self.mezcla[2]:self.num[2], self.mezcla[3]:self.num[3]}

        foto_importada = self.mi_BBDD.foto(self.relacion[0]) 
        pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(foto_importada) 
        self.v_op = tk.IntVar() 


        # ------------------- CREANDO WIDGETS --------------------

        self.op_correcta = tk.Label(master, wraplength=200)
        self.imagen = tk.Label(master, image=pic)
        self.opI = tk.Radiobutton(master, text=self.mi_BBDD.nombre(self.relacion[0]), variable=self.v_op, value=0)
        self.opII = tk.Radiobutton(master, text=self.mi_BBDD.nombre(self.relacion[1]), variable=self.v_op, value=1) 
        self.opIII = tk.Radiobutton(master, text=self.mi_BBDD.nombre(self.relacion[2]), variable=self.v_op, value=2)
        self.opIV = tk.Radiobutton(master, text=self.mi_BBDD.nombre(self.relacion[3]), variable=self.v_op, value=3) 
        self.b_siguiente = tk.Button(master, text='corregir', command=lambda:self.corregir(master))

        # --------------- GRID --------------------------

        self.op_correcta.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='en', rowspan=5)
        self.imagen.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.opI.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.opII.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.opIII.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.opIV.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.b_siguiente.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="e")
        self.imagen.mainloop() 

    def corregir(self, contenedor):

        informe = tk.Toplevel()
        self.correcto(informe)
        self.b_siguiente.grid_remove()

    def siguiente(self, contenedor):
        self.master.destroy()
        # contenedor.destroy()
        self.crear_pregunta(self.master)
        self.b_siguiente.grid()



    def correcto(self, contenedor):

        cartel = tk.Label(contenedor)
        cartel.config(text="correcto", bg="black", fg="green", font=('consola', 24))
        correccion = tk.Label(contenedor)
        correccion.config(text=self.mi_BBDD.definicion(self.relacion[0]))
        termino = tk.Label(contenedor)
        termino.config(text=self.mi_BBDD.nombre(self.relacion[0]))
        boton = tk.Button(contenedor)
        boton.config(text="siguiente", command=lambda:self.siguiente(contenedor))


        cartel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
        termino.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
        correccion.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w')
        boton.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Comment: Hola, no me queda muy claro que es contenedor, ¿es el mismo objeto recibido en el inicializador (master) o es otro? ¿Si son dos objetos distintos s crear_pregunta que le quieres pasar contenedor o master? ¿Y si es así de dónde viene contenedor?

Comment: master y contenedor son dos objetos diferentes. a crear_pregunta le quiero pasar el objeto master.

Tanto "master" como "contenedor" son objetos "Toplevel"; sólo que "contenedor" está dentro de "master"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo he entendido bien, basta con que crees un atributo de instancia en el inicializador de la clase y le asignes una referencia a la instancia de Toplevel recibida como parámetro. Hecho esto acceder al mismo desde cualquier método de instancia es trivial:

```
class Ventana:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.mi_BBDD = BBDD()
        self.master = master   # <<<< Atributo de instancia
        self.crear_pregunta(master)
```

Ahora puedes usar la referencia a tu objeto `Toplevel` desde cualquier método de instancia de la clase con solo hacer `self.master`:

```
def siguiente(self):
    contenedor.destroy() # contenedor hace referencia a otro Toplevel diferente
    self.crear_pregunta(self.master) # <<<<<<
    self.b_siguiente.grid()
```

aunque como `crear_pregunta` es otro método de instancia de la misma clase, no necesitas pasar para nada la referencia a `master` desde `siguiente`, simplemente accede a el desde dónde lo necesites usando `self.master` como se ha comentado:

```
def siguiente(self):
    contenedor.destroy() # contenedor hace referencia a otro Toplevel diferente
    self.crear_pregunta()
    self.b_siguiente.grid()

def crear_pregunta(self):
    tk.Label(self.master, text="Hola")  # <<<<<
```

Un comentario aparte, por convención las clases se nombran usando CamelCase te aconsejo que te leas Guia de estilo para código Python - PEP 8. Son una serie de convenciones generalmente adoptadas por la comunidad Python que permiten estandarizar tu código y hacerlo más legible para terceras personas:

- [PEP 8 en Español (recursospython.com).](http://www.recursospython.com/pep8es.pdf)
- [PEP 8 oficial (en ingles).](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

### Edición

El problema que causa:

```
AttributeError: 'ventana' object has no attribute 'master'
```

es la línea:

```
self.imagen.mainloop()
```

Por norma general nunca se deben tener más de un mainloop en una aplicación de tkinter, la misma idea de tener un ciclo infinito dentro de otro ciclo infinito no es muy buena en general. Esta es también una de las razones por las que solo debe haber una ventana principal (`tkinter.Tk`) y la necesidad de usar `tkinter.Toplevel` para las secundarias (que funcionan bajo el mainloop de la principal).

En nuestro caso, el `__init__` llama al método de instancia crear_pregunta antes de generar el atributo de instancia `master`:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    self.crear_pregunta(master) # Primero se llama a crear_pregunta  
    self.master = master        # Luego se crea el atributo de instancia
```

por lo tanto se ejecuta crear_pregunta cuya última línea es:

```
 self.imagen.mainloop()
```

esto es la "receta perfecta para el desastre", se genera un ciclo infinito, por lo que **el método jamás termina y no llega a retornar**, lo cual hace que **el `__init__` se quede bloqueado en la línea en la que llamado al método** `self.crear_pregunta(master)` y **`self.master` jamás es creado**. Cuando se llama a `siguiente` el atributo `master` simplemente no existe...

Si la línea `self.imagen.mainloop()` se elimina todo funciona bien, pero la imagen no se muestra. Esto es un error muy común con Tkinter, se debe a que tkinter no guarda una referencia a la imagen pasada al `Label` (u otro widget) en ningún momento. Esto hace que, en cuanto la variable se quede sin referencias, (en este caso `pic` es una variable local, que se queda sin referencias en cuanto el método retorna) el recolector de basura la elimina y el widget se queda sin la imagen cargada en memoria y no la puede mostrar.

`self.imagen.mainloop()` es un mal parche para solucionar esto, pero funciona porque evita que el método retorne como se ha comentado, por lo que `pic` mantiene su referencia. La solución correcta pasa por mantener una referencia a la imagen en todo momento mientras el widget que la muestra exista, por ejemplo con:

```
self.imagen = tk.Label(master, image=pic)
self.imagen.pic = pic
```

esto hace que se cree un nuevo atributo de instancia en el objeto `imagen` (instancia de `tkinter.Label`) al cual se asocia la instancia de la imagen (`pic`). Esto hace que mientras `imagen` exista al menos una referencia a `pic` exista evitando el problema de que el GC elimine la referencia asociada a la variable `pic` de `crear_pregunta` cuando el método retorne. Para más información ver:

- [Añadir botones con imágenes de forma dinámica, no se muestran las imágenes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/162097/15089)

Comment: justo eso intenté pero no lo reconoce como atributo:

 self.crear_pregunta(self.master)

AttributeError: 'ventana' object has no attribute 'master'

Comment: Con respecto a lo de las convenciones, dónde estuve aprendiendo decían que para python se usaba más el snake_case más que el camelCase. Debí entenderlo mal. Gracias por el apunte y por los enlaces. (Soy muy novato y tengo mucho que aprender)

Comment: Sí, seguro que lo he añadido. Respondo con todo el Código relevante para que lo veas...

Comment: `from Conexion import BBDD
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import io

class ventana_imagenes:
 def __init__(self, master):
  self.mi_BBDD = BBDD()
  self.crear_pregunta(master)
  self.master = master`

Comment: Por eso he querido meter el atributo en el constructor, y por eso me ha extrañado que me diga que la clase no tiene el atributo `master`: he hecho una respuesta (no sabía hacerlo por aqui) para poner todo el código de la clase. Por cierto muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo y por tu atención.

Comment: Definitivamente tengo que aprender a formular preguntas por aquí

Comment: jajaja no te preocupes ya te irás adaptando al sitio... Cuando quieras agregar cualquier información nueva como el código completo, simplemente usa el botón editar que hay debajo de la pregunta y añade todo lo que quieras a ella, sin borrar lo anterior si eso deja sin sentido alguna rspuesta que exista. No debes agregar nada en el apartado de respuestas si no es una respuesta a la pregunta (puedes responder a tus propias preguntas sin problemas). He editado la pregunta agregando el código, te aconsejo que elimines la "respuesta" antes que alguien empiece a votar negativo XD

Comment: De verdad que eres un crack!! jajajaja. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y conocimiento. La verdad es que tu solución resuelve el problema. Pero ahora tengo otro: y es que el `mainloop` era necesario para que me mostrara la imagen, ahora aparece el label con el tamaño de la imagen pero no muestra la imagen. Igual el problema que planteo está resuelto. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Yeah!! Ya había encontrado una solución; pero era tela de cutre. Así queda todo mucho más elegante y funciona todo mucho mejor. Ahora si que es problema resuelto. 1e99 de gracias. ;P

Comment: De nada, he editado la respuesta explicando un poco lo que ocurre con mas detalle (o lo intento al menos XD)... Un saludo.

Comment: oops. Estaré más atento a explicar bien una respuesta a una pregunta formulada. Eso sí, no lo habría sabido explicar tan bien como tu. Gracias de nuevo.