# ¿Cómo cargar una imagen a tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

**Hola Comunidad**

Estoy en desarrollo de una GUI con `tkinter` donde deseo implementar algunos widgets personalizados.

Por ejemplo, pienso colocar algunas imágenes en los botones que ofrece la librería `tkinter`, de modo de establecer un contenido mucho más atractivo. Intenté cargar estas imágenes de la forma típica en tkinter, sin embargo, aparentemente estas imágenes no fueron cargadas. A continuación, mostraré de manera resumida el código del que comento, mencionando que al ejecutarse, solo se muestra la ventana vacía.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MiApp:

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()

        imagen = tk.PhotoImage(file='mi_imagen.png')  # Imagen que deseo utilizar en tk.Button

        fm = tk.Frame(self.root)
        fm.pack()

        tk.Button(fm, image=imagen).pack()  # Botón compuesto por la imagen cargada anteriormente

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo = MiApp()
    ejemplo.mainloop()
```

Revisando antiguas publicaciones me he topado con soluciones en las que se implementa una librería llamada `PIL` para cargar imágenes. Investigué un poco acerca de ella y tal parece que dicha librería dejó de tener soporte para versiones de `Python` superior a la 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter puede manejar de forma nativa solo imágenes con formato GIF (sin animación, estáticos), PGM, y PPM. Si quieres usar imágenes en otros formatos debes convertir la imagen previamente a uno de los formatos compatibles o usar PIL.

Efectivamente PIL es un proyecto no mantenido desde el 2006 y con soporte solo para la, ahora en EOL, rama 2 de Python. No obstante, **existe un fork llamado [pillow](https://python-pillow.org/) que es el que debes usar**.

Primero instala desde [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) con pip:

> python -m pip install pillow

Aunque desde entonces ha progresado y ha seguido desde dónde PIL lo dejó, la importación y su uso no cambia en éste caso. Ejemplo de uso:

```
import io
import urllib.request
import tkinter as tk

from PIL import Image, ImageTk


URL = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png"
image = io.BytesIO(urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read())

class MiApp:

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        load = Image.open(image)
        imagen = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        fm = tk.Frame(self.root)
        fm.pack()
        btn = tk.Button(fm, image=imagen)
        btn.img_ref = imagen # Nunca te olvides de maantener una referencia
        btn.pack()

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo = MiApp()
    ejemplo.mainloop()
```

Nunca te olvides de mantener una referencia viva a la imagen en todo momento, o veras un bonito rectángulo blanco:

- [Añadir botones con imágenes de forma dinámica, no se muestran las imágenes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/162097/15089)

Uso una imagen (si, la clásica Lenna...) de dominio público que se descarga de la WEB (Wikipedia) para que el ejemplo sea reproducible directamente. Pero en tu caso sería simplemente:

```
load = Image.open('mi_imagen.png')
```